# buffered writer vs. sys out print

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I am pretty new to java and wanted to understand the reasoning why this does not work. Why does the sys out print work perfectly, but the buffered writer does not? I am just trying to understand the difference between the two/

```
//print the input matrix to the user

System.out.println("Matrix read: ");
System.out.println("------------------" +
                   "---------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d ", a[i][j]);
        bw.write(a[i][j]);
        bw.flush();
    }

    //print a blank line
    System.out.println();
```

**buffered writer output (from .txt file):**

```
     The Determinant is: 5
     The Determinant is: 3
     �The Determinant is: 64
�   ��  ���The Determinant is: 270
������   ���The Determinant is: 0
��������    ����The Determinant is: 270
������    The Determinant is: 0
    The Determinant is: 0
```

**Sys out print output:**

```
Matrix read: 
---------------------------------------
    5 
---------------------------------------
Matrix read: 
---------------------------------------
    2     3 
---------------------------------------
    5     9 
---------------------------------------
Matrix read: 
---------------------------------------
    3    -2     4 
---------------------------------------
   -1     5     2 
---------------------------------------
   -3     6     4 
---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a raw `int` with

```
bw.write(a[i][j]);
```

(if you want the same thing written to your `BufferedWriter`) you need to *format* your output the same way. You could use `String.format` and something like

```
bw.write(String.format("%5d ", a[i][j]));
```

And, you'll need to add a new line (where you call `System.out.println`) if you want it to be identical, like

```
bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

With `write()` you write bytes. In your first matrix you have the numerical value 5. If you use `write(5)`, you write the byte value 5 which is a non-printable character that the text editor you are using is displaying somehow. If you use a hexdump utility, you will see that it acutally is the byte `5`.

To the `printf` function you five a format string with which you tell it how to format the argument, which is the number `5`. `%5d` here means format the number as string with at least 5 width, filled with spaces in front. and then a space afterwards.

If you want to have the same effect on your buffered writer, wrap it in a `PrintWriter` and use the same `printf` method and arugments and you will get the same result. If you only want to format the number as String in the `BufferedWriter`, you have to convert your number to a String befory you write it, e. g. with `Integer.toString(5).getBytes()` and then write this byte array with the according `write()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`; to get the same behavior, try using a `PrintStream` (or `PrintWriter`) instantiated with your file name and use the `print`/`println`/`format` methods.

The `BufferedWriter.write(int c)` methods interprets the `int` parameter as a character, so if you pass `32`, it's going to print a space character; that's most likely not what you want here.