# System.out.printf(“%4d”) in BufferedWriter / FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I made a multiplication table. The problem is that the table is not ordered as it should.

If I want just to print it on the screen, then I use this `System.out.printf(“%4d”)`. How can I resolve this problem with `BufferedWriter`?

Instead of this:

```
Irj be egy szamot:
5
1 2 3 4 5 
2 4 6 8 10 
3 6 9 12 15 
4 8 12 16 20 
5 10 15 20 25 `
```

I want this:

```
Irj be egy szamot: 
5
1  2  3  4  5 
2  4  6  8 10 
3  6  9 12 15 
4  8 12 16 20 
5 10 15 20 25 `
```

Here is my code:

```
public class EgyszerEgy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a;
        int b;

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("EgyszerEgy.txt");
            BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(writer);

            Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Irj be egy szamot: ");
            int szam = tastatur.nextInt();

            for (a = 1; a <= szam; ++a) {
                for (b = 1; b <= szam; ++b) {
                    int eredmeny = a * b;
                    String eredmenyString = String.valueOf(eredmeny);
                    bf.write(eredmenyString);
                    bf.write(" ");
                }
                bf.newLine();
            }
            bf.flush();
            bf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        // Kiolvasas
        //String result;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("EgyszerEgy.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String result;
            while ((result = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `System.out.println(result);` with `System.out.printf("%4d", result);`.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416078/buffered-writer-vs-sys-out-print

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So Marvin did better than Marvin *(same person)*? 

Comment: I think I'm faster in spotting my errors than you are, too late **again** :P

Comment: Note that although both Marvin's suggestions have good answers, the questions themselves are very unwieldy and badly formatted. **Both are about streams as well instead of writers.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know how to wrap a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) with a [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). Now wrap it again with a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), which has the [`printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) methods.

You should also use try-with-resources. It was added in Java 7, so there is absolutely no good reason not to use it, unless you're stuck on Java 6 or earlier.

Same for using NIO.2 API instead of the old File I/O API.

```
Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Irj be egy szamot: ");
int szam = tastatur.nextInt();

try (PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("EgyszerEgy.txt")))) {
    for (int a = 1; a <= szam; ++a) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= szam; ++b) {
            int eredmeny = a * b;
            fout.printf("%3d ", eredmenyString);
        }
        fout.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the exact same formatting as `printf` by using `String.format` and writing the result to the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Why would you need to use `String.format` explicitly? Why not just use a `PrintStream`?

Comment: To get the spacing that the question asks for without doing anything differently. It wants `"%4d"` after all.

Comment: Either use `String.format` *or* use `PrintWriter.printf`. Doing both is redundant!